# Is the ideal $I=(x_1 x_5 - x_2 x_4 , x_1 x_6 - x_3 x_4)$ of $k[x_1,...,x_6]$ a radical ideal? Is it a prime ideal?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Is the ideal $I=(x_1 x_5 - x_2 x_4 , x_1 x_6 - x_3 x_4)$ of $k[x_1,...,x_6]$ a radical ideal? Is it a prime ideal?

thanks

Comment: I tried to use initial ideals but it became harder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you compute a Gröbner basis for $I$, you will get that you need one additional generator, namely $x_1x_3x_5-x_1x_2x_6=x_1(x_3x_5-x_2x_6)$. Thus $x_1$ vanishes on the zero set of the ideal, but $x_1 \not \in I$, as in Alex Becker's anser above.

Your ideal in fact decomposes as $I= I_{minors} \cap \langle x_1, x_4 \rangle$, where $I_{minors}$ is the ideal of $2 \times 2$-minors of a generic matrix
$$ \begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\ x_4 & x_5 & x_6\end{bmatrix}.$$

So the "reason" the ideal is not prime is that you didn't include all minors.

**ADDED** To see the decomposition $I=I_{minors} \cap \langle x_1,x_4 \rangle$, we show first the $\subseteq$-direction. But this is clear, because the generators of $I$ are a subset of the generators of $I_{minors}$, and they clearly lie in $\langle x_1,x_4\rangle$. For the other direction, one notices that already two of the generators of $I_{minors}$ lie in $I$. The last one, $x_2x_6-x_3x_5$, can be multiplied by elements of $\langle x_1,x_4\rangle$ to give $x_1x_3x_5-x_1x_2x_6$, wich lies in $I$, because it is part of a Gröbner basis of $I$, as explained above. The the decomposition is shown.

Now it is a result that any determinantal ideal is prime (try Google), and so $I$ is an intersection of prime ideals. Thus $I$ is radical, because an ideal is radical if and only if it decomposes as an intersection of radical ideals (easy exercise!). (*for a hint: suppose $f^k \in I$. Then $f^k$ is also contained in all the components of $I$, but they are all radical...*)

Comment: I think $I= I_{minors} \cap \langle x_1, x_4 \rangle$ deserves a proof. Furthermore, you could add that this shows that $I$ is radical (since determinantal ideals are prime).

Comment: @user26857 Yes, it deserves proof, but I don't believe it should be too difficult. I did the computation in Macaulay2 which I trust more than myself.

Comment: Minor point: my answer is no longer "above".

Comment: @AlexBecker Or is it? (Both answers currently have a score of 5, which leads to the well-known Schrödinger's Answer Paradox).

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld At time of writing, his had 5 and mine had 4.

Comment: @Fredrik Meyer: thanks. can you please write  user26857's comment in details specially about "this shows that I is radical"? you see  my reputation:40

Comment: @user10000 I've expanded somewhat on my answer. Does this clarify?

Answer (score 7):

It is not prime since
$$x_1(x_3x_5-x_2x_6)=x_3(x_1x_5-x_2x_4)-x_2(x_1x_6-x_3x_4)\in I$$
but $x_1\notin I$ because every nonzero element of $I$ has degree at least $2$, and $x_3x_5-x_2x_6\notin I$ because every element of degree $2$ in $I$ is a $k$-linear combination of $x_1x_5-x_2x_4$ and $x_1x_6-x_3x_4$ and so cannot involve either of the terms $x_3x_5$ or $x_2x_6$.

Note that this is taking advantage of the fact that $I$ is homogeneous.